# Strange line above the background image on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a problem with the website of my client. On mobile devices, there is a strange line over the background image (background aligned to bottom, repeat-x). On the desktop, everything looks correct. Has anyone met with such a case?
If I delete the background image, the line also disappears. I tried to change the background from png to jpg, but that did not help.

Thank you in advance for any help.

[Link to website](http://www.lena-hausmeisterservice.de/gebaeudereinigung/)

[Screenshot from mobile device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SKCc.jpg)

Comment: this is in you image gradient effect

Comment: Gaurav Aggarwal, background image has a line at the bottom but at the top (where unwanted line appears) there is a white background